# Board review: is this PIC16F877 RS232+ICSP board correct/robust?

Tags: pic, digital-logic, rs232, programmer

I want to make my own development board based on a PIC, to make a RS232 bootloader from scratch. It's been a while I haven't used a PIC, and it was on a ready made development board.

I've looked around on the web and designed what I think is a minimalistic RS232 and ICSP board based on a 16F877. Could you review it and tell me if it'll work, if it can be made more robust (for future projects as well)?

Sorry if the symbols look funny, I use DesignSpark PCB and I usually go first with the models in the ModelSource database. 
[image]

In particular, the ICSP is going to be a ICD3 which is apparently high voltage... Not good for the MAX233 and the LM340.

P.S: Those are SMD components, therefore my "breadboard" will actually be a draft PCB from a PCB house

Comment: The only thing that jumps out at me is that Vpp can be as much as 12 volts under HV programming. This part seems to be capable of LV programming, so it may not be an issue though. I did not do a pin-number audit or anything like that, so don't consider this a stamp of approval....

Comment: Leave the footprint audit to me. ;) I will use the ICD3 programmer, which is high voltage... Not good for the MAXc233 and the LM340 is it?

Comment: What about a schottky from 5v to R4 and from the R2out of the MAX233 to 5V?

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about Vpp crossing the 4.7k. I was more concerned with U9. A clamp diode from R2OUT to 5V should do the job. You may want to bump the resistance of R4 a little though. But overall this may just be needless handwringing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at the datasheet for the MAX232 and add the capacitors that are missing.  There should be 4 capacitors PLUS the bypass cap for a total of 5 capacitors near the MAX232.

I don't have the datasheet for the 16f877 in front of me right now but there should be two sets of Vdd & Vss pins.  I see only one set connected.  The chip is NOT reliable if you don't have both sets connected.

You should have a bypass cap right beside each of those sets of power pins.

[Edit]

I see now that you are using the MAX233, not the 232 like I had thought.  What you have looks okay.

Possibly the only potential problem is when you are programming the chip with your ICD3.

You show a 4k7 pull-up from !MCLR to Vdd.  If you don't have sufficient load on your 5V supply, the programming voltage will raise the 5V rail higher than allowed.

There are several easy options to fix this.

- Increase the value of R4 to 39k as per Microchip's datasheet
- Ensure that there is sufficient load on the 5V rail to ensure that Vpp being raised to +13V does not cause the 5V rail to increase.
- put a diode in series with R4 (cathode towards !MCLR)

Your schematic looks good and should get you going quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've checked in the datasheet, the MAX233 version has only one bypass cap (page 24). Also both the sets of VSS/VDD pins on the 16F877 are connected and bypassed; or am I missing something? Otherwise, is it ok and as robust as it can be (no improvement)?

Comment: I thought that was weird too, but the 233 seems to have the caps built in. It's the future, man.

Comment: Okay - I finally had a chance to take a quick look at the MAX233 datasheet. I'm wrong about the capacitor connections and I'll modify my answer when I get to my computer.