# PIC16F877 blink program uploads correctly but nothing happens - hardware or software mistake?

Tags: microcontroller, led, pic, programming, debugging

I made a custom board based on a PIC16F877 but for now I only soldered the minimum. I installed MPLABX and the XC8 compiler, connected the ICD3 to the board, adapted a "blink" example to RD0 where my LED is, programmed the PIC and ran the program. Nothing has happened.

I removed power to the board and applied 5V (my Vcc) across the R+LED (- to cathode obviously), and it lit up... So I checked the footprint in the datasheet, RD0 is really there and I had little doubt since it's a plug&play CAD component from Modelsource.

So what's wrong then? Programming went fine, here is the log:

(ICD3)

> Connecting to MPLAB ICD 3...
>
> Currently loaded firmware on ICD 3
>
> Firmware Suite Version.....01.36.10
>
> Firmware type..............Midrange
>
> Target voltage detected
>
> Target device PIC16F877 found.
>
> Device ID Revision = 6
>
> The following memory area(s) will be programmed:
>
> program memory: start address = 0x0, end address = 0x7ff
>
> configuration memory
>
> Device Erased...
>
> Programming...
>
> Programming/Verify complete

(output)

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 155ms)
>
> Loading code from
>   C:/Users/[...]/MPLABXProjects/test.X/dist/default/production/test.X.production.hex...
>
> Loading completed
>
> Connecting to programmer...
>
> Programming target...
>
> Programming completed
>
> Running target...

If programming was ok, that means the frequency was set up properly. I'm not sure if it's a software or a hardware mistake, so here is the schematic:
[image]
([bigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v86PG.png)) (the jumper is not connected, such that TX and RX are disconnected)

Code:

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000

#include <xc.h>

// BEGIN CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = HS // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = ON // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT enabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR enabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF // Low-Voltage (Single-Supply) In-Circuit Serial Programming Enable bit (RB3 is digital I/O, HV on MCLR must be used for programming)
#pragma config CPD = OFF // Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit (Data EEPROM code protection off)
#pragma config WRT = OFF // Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits (Write protection off; all program memory may be written to by EECON control)
#pragma config CP = OFF // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit (Code protection off)
//END CONFIG

int main()
{
  TRISDbits.TRISD0 = 0; //RD0 as Output PIN
  while(1)
  {
    RD0 = 1;  // LED ON
    __delay_ms(1000); // 1 Second Delay
    RD0 = 0;  // LED OFF
    __delay_ms(1000); // 1 Second Delay
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I have tried debugging it via "Build for debugging Main project" and "Debug main project" but it says "[Programming/Verify complete.] The target device is not ready for debugging. [...]"...

Comment: `#pragma config WDTE = ON` Probably not the cause, but the watchdog timer will keep resetting your code periodically.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Setting it to OFF didn't solve anything as you suspected though :(

Comment: There are multiple pinouts, depending on the package: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/30292D.pdf - are you sure you have the right one?

Comment: Pretty sure, as PLCC and QFP have different envelope widths and yet the chip is soldered nicely. Even then, the programming pins are at different places between the two packages, and yet programming works flawlessly it appears.

Comment: Have you verified that the ICD3 is not holding it in reset?

Comment: "If programming was ok, that means the frequency was set up properly." ... I program processors for old legacy boards that do not have an ICD connector using an ICD3 along with a "Universal Programming Module" which has a ZIF socket. No clock source is connected, so I'm pretty sure that programming success does NOT mean your clock source is working.

Comment: @Tut - this! ICD provides clock during programming so you can program the wrong clock into the PIC.

Comment: @OlegMazurov Exactly, you can program the wrong clock settings or have no working clock at all, and still get the part to program. That said, I do believe "FOSC = HS" is correct.

Comment: Very interesting comment, I didn't know the ICD was providing the clock. I'll check the voltage across the quartz tomorrow (hopefully the clock is not buried further in the chip) to see if it's working.

Comment: You probably should be asking, "why can't I debug?" If you could debug, you could pause the execution and see where your program is. If you asked why can't I debug, I would guess that something is wrong with your oscillator.

Comment: @MattAnderson: Spot on. I measured the potential on each side of the crystal, and noticed one of them was different from the pins. Turns out the pad wasn't soldered properly (a magnifier didn't help)... Geez. Post that as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: I posted it as an answer and some powerful person made it a comment instead... All answers aren't long

Comment: Dwayne Reid's answer should theoretically be a comment as well as long as it's not proven that his hunch is right. Being a moderator requires decisions to be made... 
Just re-post, perhaps talking like you knew exactly what was wrong, and it should stay there so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you can't debug the project is a good indication that your hardware set up or configuration bits are incorrect.  Just because you can program the device is no indication that the micro is receiving a valid clock signal.  Because your config bits look ok, no clock signal is the most likely problem.

Answer (score 1):

1) What is the connection from the MAX233 to MCLR all about?

I would remove R3 and see what happens.

2) Change your configuration word to disable the watchdog until you have everything sorted out.

Comment: It is to be able to reset the micro from the control PC, as designed in http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/163742/how-to-protect-a-max232-from-pic-programming-high-voltages
I'll remove that tomorrow, hopefully it's that because I have no other clue :( The WDT is now OFF, I haven't changed it back.